# Does any interval between points in Fat Cantor set have positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Let $C$ be a [Fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) defined on $[0,1]$, and Lebesgue measure $m (C) >0$.
Is it true that, if $a<b$ and $(a,b) \cap C \neq \varnothing$, then $m ((a,b) \cap C) >0$?

I believe this to be true, but I find it hard to explain formally.
Roughly, if $(a,b) \cap C$ contains at least one remaining interval at a certain stage, then the argument that $C$ has positive measure also guarantees not all measure in $(a,b)$ is hollowed out, i.e., it left some measure.
Since at later stage, the remaining intervals looks so "dense" (in verbal sense), I find it reasonable, but these intervals are scattered irregularly, I don't know how to write a formal proof.

Edit: Originally I wrote close interval, and I soon find the answer to be negative, but still want to know the case for open interval.
Sorry to the first answerer.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask, if $a\lt b$ and if $(a,b)\cap C\ne\emptyset$, does $(a,b)\cap C$ have positive measure?

Comment: Ah! The original one is false, and this is a better question.

Comment: I feel pretty sure the answer to the second question is "yes"

Comment: Edited. I too find it obvious to be yes, just don't know how to prove.

Comment: What is your definition of "fat Cantor set"?  You can certainly construct a Cantor set that has positive measure but which has measure zero on some intervals.

Comment: I only know the construction in linked Wikipedia.

Comment: @Violapterin - if you read that article fully, you will see that the name "Fat Cantor set" is commonly applied to the result of any Cantor-like construction where at each step every remaining interval has some open sub-interval removed, in such a way that the overall measure does not converge to $0$. Whether your question is true or false depends on the relative size of those sub-intervals. For example, if you remove middle thirds from intervals below $1/2$, but middle fourths from intervals above $1/2$, you get a Fat Cantor set for which $m((0,1/2) \cap C) = 0$, but $m((1/2,1) \cap C) > 0$.

Answer (score 5):

The question has been edited after I posted this answer.

No,  you remove some intervals to construct the fat Cantor set. So there are intervals for which the interscetion with $C$ is empty.

Comment: You are right. Still, I want to know the case of open interval, and I will let question open for a while.

Answer (score 1):

For the SVC or "remove the middle fourths" fat Cantor set, the answer to the adjusted question (throwing out cases where $(a,b)\cap C = \emptyset$) is yes.

The key understanding here that if $[p, q]$ is one of the closed intervals in the construction of the set, then $[p,q]\cap C$ is a scaled-down version of $C$ itself. In particular, the affine map $x \mapsto \frac {x-p}{q-p}$ is a bijection between $[p,q] \cap C$ and $C$ itself, as can be seen by noting that it carries $[p,q] \to [0,1]$ and the middle fourth of $[p,q]$ to the middle fourth of $[0,1]$, and similarly for all other removed subintervals. Thus $m([p,q]\cap C) = \frac {q - p}2$.

Now let $c \in (a,b) \cap C$. There is some interval $(c - \epsilon, c+\epsilon)$ about $c$ inside $(a,b)$, and because the width of the closed intervals in the construction that contain $c$ go to $0$, there has to be some such interval $[p,q]$ with $c \in [p,q] \subset (c - \epsilon, c+\epsilon)\subset(a,b)$. Therefore $$m((a,b) \cap C) \ge m([p,q] \cap C) > 0$$